# Spring boot maven multiple module

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I write a simple spring boot multiple module. a parent module have two sub-module access and web module. i put all module config below. this sample project work correctly when it is a one module but when i put it in multiple module throw this exception

**update : full stack trace**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: --=
>       at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.parse(SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.(SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.configurePropertySources(SpringApplication.java:443)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.configureEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:414)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:284)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
>       at com.spring.controller.Application.main(Application.java:21)

i will put more info about sample if it need.

**parent module:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<name>parent</name>
<groupId>com.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring-boot.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>access</module>
    <module>web</module>
</modules>
```

and **access module** config is this

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>access</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and web module config is this:

```
 <parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>access</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.spring.controller.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and application class code is:

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan("com.spring.controller")
 @EnableJpaRepositories
 @Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
 @EnableAutoConfiguration
 @PropertySource("application.properties")
 public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
 }
}
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace?

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson, i put full stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

The exception states that you are miss using the `SpringApplication.run(...)` method. It looks like you are passing --= as arguments.

Check out the Spring Boot guide for its usage or give us your code snippet.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Edit 1 :

The problem comes from the arguments of your run configuration.

The parameters found within args are incorrect. `--=` is not acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. please look at my updated question. i add application class.

Comment: The problem comes from the arguments of your run configuration.

The parameters found within args are incorrect.